# Namespaced Controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Regarding to PSR-0 standards it says each class must have a namespace. 
So, is it necessary that controllers must be in namespace as well?

Comment: Is it necessary that your controllers take part in PSR-0? Some might say no. If you do want to, then yes, they have to be namespaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your controllers to be PSR-0 compliant, then they have to be namespaced.

Laravel makes it super easy to use a single namespace for all your controllers, without having to set it manually on every route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'ACME\Controllers', function ()
{
    // Routes to: ACME\Controllers\Home@index
    Route::get('/', 'Home');

    // Routes to: ACME\Controllers\Admin@orders
    Route::get('admin/orders', 'Admin@orders');
}]);
```

Comment: +1 for showing me you can add namespaces to routing groups, I'll have to go clean up some routes :)